# How to upload image to controller using jquery - Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to upload an image to my public folder like below. But when i save the product, i get the error. What could be the issue the error below is thrown ?

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

**JS**

```
function save(token,price,image)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "/products",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        _token: token,
        price: price,
        image:image
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataResult){
    }
});
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();     
}
```

**Response**

```
array (
  '_token' => '1TnztJRZ7vc780ehUt3yZmJofZOJYVclnMQRS929',
  'price' => '10',
  'productImage' => 'C:\\fakepath\\bankis-4-FP.jpg',
)
```

Comment: `$input['image']` appears to be a string, not an image. If you're attempting to upload binary file data you'll need to amend your JS logic to send a FormData object in the AJAX request, and then read the file data in Laravel.

Comment: You need to send data from javascript wrapped in FormData and not as a plain javascript object. `const data = new FormData(this) and $.ajax({ data:data,...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your form you need to send `FormData` in your `ajax` call in this case you can get `productImage` as `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` and you can access `extension()` method, so in you blade you will add

```
<form id="upload_form">

...

</form>
```

And your Javascript code will be

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "/products",
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: (data) => {

        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Now in your controller you have access to `productImage` as an `UploadedFile`

```
$request->file('productImage')->extension();

// Or

$request->file('productImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the uploaded file object before you can call methods on it

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    //Validate request data
    $validatedData = $request->validate($rules, $request->except('image'));

    if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
        
        $filename = time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->extension();
        $validatedData['image'] = $request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename);
    }  


    $model->fill($validatedData);
    $model->save();

}
```